# Linkedin Permissions : only serving current position informations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, linkedin-api

This question is related to the same one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116853/new-linkedin-permissions-accessing-past-positions-and-educations-using-rails-li), but still i am facing the same problem that linkedin is only serving the current position informations , how can i get the past positions & education details using the [linkedin gem](https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin) in Rails,my linkedin controller has been shown below, need your assistance.

```
   require 'linkedin'

   class LinkedinUserController < ApplicationController

   def init_client
     key = "XXXXXX"
     secret = "XXXXXX"
     linkedin_configuration = { :site => 'https://api.linkedin.com',
        :authorize_path => '/uas/oauth/authenticate',
        :request_token_path =>'/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_fullprofile+r_emailaddress+r_network+r_contactinfo',
        :access_token_path => '/uas/oauth/accessToken' }

     @linkedin_client = LinkedIn::Client.new(key, secret,linkedin_configuration)
   end

   def auth
     init_client
     request_token = @linkedin_client.request_token(:oauth_callback => "http://#{request.host_with_port}/linkedin/callback")
     session[:rtoken] = request_token.token
     session[:rsecret] = request_token.secret
     redirect_to @linkedin_client.request_token.authorize_url
   end

   def callback
     init_client
     if session[:atoken].nil?
       pin = params[:oauth_verifier]
       atoken, asecret =  @linkedin_client.authorize_from_request(session[:rtoken], session[:rsecret], pin)
       session[:atoken] = atoken
       session[:asecret] = asecret
     else
       @linkedin_client.authorize_from_access(session[:atoken], session[:asecret])
     end

     c = @linkedin_client
     c.profile(:fields=>["first_name","last_name","headline","positions","educations"])
   end
   end
```

Comment: Do you want details of authorized user?or details of connections for that particular authorize user?

Comment: I just want details of that particular authorized user , particularly all past position details & education details.

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#profile this can help you,updated linkedIn API profile fields

Comment: I have referred the same to get the details Cris , in that Document they have said that 'positions' attribute will return the collection of positions, but i don't know why linkedin only returning the current position status.

Comment: try this, c.profile(:fields => %w(positions)) to get at least positions

Comment: Wow Cris, it is working now , what was the problem before?. I think the fields should be specific with respect to the attributes.i mean basic_profile should be in one set & full_profile fields should be another,we cant combine these two fields inside one.right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn is very particular about access to profile fields and you cannot combine multiple fields which requires 2 different access.
so when you try to get just position details by `c.profile(:fields => %w(positions))` it assumes the access of type 'r_basicprofile' whereas educations field require access of type 'r_fullprofile'.so try 2 seperate API calls to retrieve both fields.

"first_name","last_name","headline","positions" available for 'r_basicprofile' member permission,so they can be combined together.